# How to transform a cluster of links (in a card) to only one link on the title?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, seo

I have a card with 3 links inside (with the same url) and it's not good for SEO. I would like to have only one link on the title (H3) but keep all the card clickable. It's possible in css ?

```
<article class="overflow-hidden transition-shadow duration-300 rounded">
  <%= link_to post_path(post.slug),aria: {label:'article'}, class: "inline-block text-black no-underline transition-colors duration-200 hover:text-deep-purple-accent-700" do %>
    <%= image_tag photo(post, 400, 400), class:"object-cover w-full h-64 rounded-lg"%>
  <% end %>

  <div class="py-2">
    <%= link_to post_path(post.slug), aria: {label:'article'}, class: "inline-block mb-3 text-black no-underline transition-colors duration-200 hover:text-deep-purple-accent-700" do %>
      <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold leading-5"><%= post.title %></h3>
    <% end %>
    <span class="absolute bg-gray-500 text-white right-4 top-4 py-1 px-2 flex rounded-lg">
      <svg>...</svg>
      <%= post.reading_time %> min
    </span>

    <p class="mb-4 text-gray-700"><%= post.meta_description %></p>
    <div class="flex space-x-4">
      <%= link_to post_path(post.slug),aria: {label:'article'}, class: "flex items-start text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-200 hover:text-deep-purple-accent-700 group" do %>
        <div class="mr-2">
          <svg>....</svg>
        </div>
        <p class="font-semibold"><%= post.comments_count %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using CSS. Just copy the given below CSS and use it within the `<a>` tag. By using this all parent div areas will act as a clickable links.

```css
.stretched-link::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>I am not anchor tag.</h1>
    <h2>I am not anchor tag.</h2>
    <h3>I am not anchor tag.</h3>
    <a href="#" class="stretched-link">I am an anchor tag</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The H3 link is in a div, but this div is not the card's div parent.

https://codepen.io/tioneb12/pen/YzVyrPv

Comment: It will act as a link within its parent scope.